# Electron - how to handle ipc with Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ipc, electron

I've recently started learning Angular2 and I'm doing this by porting an electron app I made with Angular1.5 over to Angular2.4.2

One thing I haven't been able to figure out so far is how best to handle the ipc events.

- Should I use observables for this? if so, how?
- Should I just use `ipcRenderer.on(...)` in my classes?

Right now I've tried turning the ipc events into observables with the `.fromEventPattern()` method, but my observables are only getting new data *once* instead of every time.

Conversion function in service:

```
createObservable(renderer:any, channel: string) : Observable<Array<any>> 
{
    function add (handler) { renderer.on(channel, handler) }
    function remove (handler) { renderer.removeListener(channel, handler) }
    function selector (ev: any, data: any ) {
        if (data.err) throw new Error(data.err)
            return data.content
    }
    return Observable.fromEventPattern(add, remove, selector)
}
```

Component code

```
const {ipcRenderer} = electron
export class ContactDetailComponent implements OnInit {
foundObservable:Observable<any> = this.ipcService.createObservable(ipcRenderer,'found')
[...]
constructor (private ipcService:IpcService) {}
ngOnInit(){
    this.foundObservable.subscribe(
        data => { this.zone.run(this.foundDone(data)); console.log('hello?') },
        err => { this.zone.run(this.genericFail.bind(this, 'found')) }
    )
}
[...]
foundDone(data): any
{
    this.loading = false
    this.editMode = false
    this.contact = data[0]
}
genericFail (type, err)
{
    this.zone.run(()=>{
        this.loading = false
        if (type === 'found') this.editMode = false
        else if (type === 'delete') this.deleted = true
        return this.setMessage('error', err)
    })      
}
```